# Group policy component showing GUID not description

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-10

I have found when I do a GPresult /h, and take a look at the generated report, I see a "Component Name" in the "Component Status" section has a GUID rather than a description. A screenshot of this is below:

[image: GPResult]

Can anyone tell me how to determine what this is? It doesn't currently seem to be causing any issues, but it doesn't seem like it should be doing this, and should instead show me a component name not GUID.

I don't think the GUID is that of a GPO, and is instead the GUID of a GP component. I also don't know how to determine which GPO is causing this to show in the GPResult.

EDIT: Result of RSOP data, with no errors in user config, which is where this shows up:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The problem is not a faulty GPO as I assumed, but a bug in Windows 10 1703 / RemoteApp. If you / your users don't have local admin rights, the policy will fail because they can't read the permissions from the registry. Your settings apply correctly, so that's no problem for you, but a display bug. The wrongly shown GUID seems to be a part of this. [KB4048954](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4048954/windows-10-update-kb4048954) fixes the problem itself.

---

<del>You can [search for GPOs](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/grouppolicy/2009/03/13/search-gpo-how-to-find-a-group-policy-object/) in the GP management console using the search option. There, you can filter by GUID etc.</del>

<del>Usually a GPO showing its GUID is a deleted or inaccessible object, due to a missing file/registry entry or wrong permissions.</del>

<del>Check the [RSOP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758010(v=ws.10).aspx) and eventlogs of the server, too. I always could figure out which GPO was causing the errors and hunt down the culprit (culprit being another sysadmin, or someone meddling with permissions or once even a broken DFS sysvol-replication).</del>

Comment: Thanks. So if when doing a search for this by GUID, it finds nothing, how do I proceed to remove it from GP processing? Is this possibly down to replication issues?

Comment: Is there anything in your eventlogs regarding replication or some other error? In your case, I don't suspect replication to be the culprit. Please use the mentioned RSOP to look for the GPO and what settings it configures. From there you'll probably find the error.

Comment: There looks to be one event for DFSR each morning coinciding with our backups, where replication pauses for "backup or restore" but otherwise no errors seen. When I run RSOP, there is an error (software deploy pending restart) for computer config, but no errors for user config. User config error information also shows the component name as a GUID, but says success. Will add screenshot to my question.

Comment: Try searching in your GPO console to search for _all_ GPOs, sort by GUID and look for yours. Your DFS errors have nothing to do with GPO, presumably.

Comment: It does not appear there is a GPO with that GUID. Is the GUID seen under the component name even a GPO GUID? That section isn't listing GPOs is it? I thought it was listing components, such as driver maps, deployed printers and scripts etc.

Comment: Ah...sorry, I can't read (again). Do you by any chance use "RemoteApp"? Please also check if this registry key exists: `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\GPExtensions\{4D2F9B6F-1E52-4711-A382-6A8B1A003DE6}]`

Comment: We do deploy the default connection URL for the RemoteApp and Resource feature, if that's what you mean? This is in an effort for published desktops and collections to be automatically added to a users' profile. I do indeed have that key, and see the extension name(?) is RADCProcessGroupPolicyEx

Comment: Alright. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Doesn't look like that update exists in our WSUS server, so might be superseded by a newer update (not sure what KB would replace it). I suppose as it applies policies correctly, it doesn't really matter, although I do see the same behaviour on a 2012 R2 RDSH server. Thanks!